# How to create a closure from String in Dart?

Tags: reflection, closures, dart, dart-mirrors

How to use dart-mirror API to create a anonymous closure dynamically?

Like as the interpreter, compile the code during run-time.

```
var funcstr='bool (String s){ return (s==null); }';
var func=parseStr(funcstr);
// func(s)-> s==null;
var r=func('false');
// r=false;
```

so, how to do with "parseStr"?

my project:
http://github.com/stevehsu77/surebet

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no way to do this. Dart has no `eval` and no code generation at runtime.

But it is something Gilad Bracha (the language spec lead of Dart) wants to have (https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/6O4g7eEHgOU) at least for the development environment.

Also

> We’d like to support more powerful reflective features in the future. These would include mirror builders, designed to allow programs to extend and modify themselves, and a mirror-based debugging API as well.

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/reflection-with-mirrors/

So it'll probably be supported some time in the future. But right now it's not possible.

Comment: I am trying to use dart-js to call 'eval' in DOM. However, dart-js cannot run under dartvm. Maybe doing some injection to vm or create a bridge between dart and DOM. Something like as js-interop. But I have no idea now. Keep trying hardly, anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, Dart does not have eval, however it is possible to load new source code in another isolate using [spawnUri()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_isolate/Isolate.html#spawnUri).

I am not sure if there are any examples of how to use this. Perhaps post a message on the dart [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc).

Using isolates and spawnUri() is quite a different than using eval, so it may not be the right fit for your project.

Comment: An easy way to implement 'spawnUri()' as below
`main(args, msg)
   {
     vm_main(msg);
   }

 vm_main(msg)
 {

 }`

so that you can `spawn(vm_main,msg);` or `spawnUri(uri,args,msg);`

Comment: I haven't tried using spawnUri() before, can the uri be an arbitrary http uri? Or are there some restrictions?